# In Asp.net List view Image is not showing to Interface But the image is already In Database

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

List view code:

```
<section id="service" class="bg-light paddingtop-60">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DoctorSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:eSoft_DHD_BusinessConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT DoctorChambers.City, DoctorMains.DoctorName, DoctorMains.Title, DoctorMains.ProfileImage, DoctorMains.DoctorID FROM DoctorChambers RIGHT OUTER JOIN DoctorMains
                    ON DoctorChambers.DoctorMain_DoctorID = DoctorMains.DoctorID WHERE (DoctorChambers.City LIKE '%' + @City + '%') AND (DoctorMains.DoctorName LIKE '%' + @DoctorName + '%')">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="City" SessionField="DocCity" Type="String"/>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="DoctorName" SessionField="DocSession" Type="String"/>
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource> 
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <asp:ListView ID="DoctorListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="DoctorSqlDataSource">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table class ="table table-bordered">
                                <tr class="bg-gray">
                                    <td class ="col-md-2">
                                        <asp:Image ID="ProfileImage" runat="server" Width="120" Height="120" CssClass="person img-circle" ImageUrl='<%# "PublicPages/Search.aspx?ImageID="+Eval("DoctorId") %>' />
                                        <%--<asp:Image ID="ProfileImage" runat="server" Width="120" Height="120" CssClass="person img-circle" ImageUrl=' ~/PublicPages/Search.aspx?ImageID=<%#Eval("DoctorId") %>' />--%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-4">
                                        <asp:Label ID="DoctorNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DoctorName") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-6">
                                        <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-8">
                                        <asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            <table class ="table table-bordered">
                                <tr style="">
                                    <td class ="col-md-2">
                                        <asp:Image ID="ProfileImage" runat="server" Width="120" Height="120" CssClass="person img-circle" ImageUrl='<%# "PublicPages/Search.aspx?ImageID="+Eval("DoctorId") %>' />
                                        <%-- <asp:Image ID="ProfileImage" runat="server" Width="120" Height="120" CssClass="person img-circle" ImageUrl=' ~/PublicPages/Search.aspx?ImageID=<%#Eval("DoctorId") %>' />--%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-4">
                                        <asp:Label ID="DoctorNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DoctorName") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-6">
                                        <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="col-md-8">
                                        <asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <table runat="server" style="">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>No data was returned.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What happens when you go to `PublicPages/Search.aspx?ImageID="+Eval("DoctorId")` (With a suitable doctor ID)_? Do you get an image? If not, what goes wrong? "Not showing" is a user's description of the problem. You're a programmer, so please give us a programmer's description and explain what debugging you've done and what specific errors or problems you're experiencing.

Comment: This Problem was Solved . This problem was created for the missing of Data BindingSource and the wrong Connection String.

Comment: This Problem was Solved . This problem was created for the missing of Data BindingSource and the wrong Connection String.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem was Solved . This problem was created for the missing of Data BindingSource and the Connection String.